# several doubts about node.js and php

Tags: php, node.js, backend, dnode

In my case
i'm making something like this :- http://sketchtoy.com/65641233

Not that website , i'm talking about the diagram. In my case i will have a page where a client can buy access to some service (done in node.js ). Each user buying service will be assigned a new node.js script file. So what to use in this case ? I want to dynamically add more and more node.js scripts and it should be controlled by a webpage where user can login

What i came across is something like this :- 
service1.myaddress.com
service2.myaddress.com

I think this isn't efficient , cause i can have 100s of service page

2) If you ask me to use php , then how to make node.js and php call each other? I came across Dnode but i have no idea if that is effective in my case or not.

3) While reading a source code of php and node.js script, i came across this :-

In node.js script :-

```
var url = 'http://'+name+'/exec.php';
request(url, function(err, response, body){});
```

And that exec.php contains some imp functions , is this is how we are supposed to call a php function from node.js ? and what if a random unauthorized client visits **http://'+name+'/exec.php**  , will that function in the exec.php will be executed ?

Comment: Please clarify your question, as it currently stands its far to vague to answer - is your question about app architecture? node <--> php communication? Or are you looking for the pros and cons of the two different software stacks / languages?

Comment: To be precised my question is about communication between'em also how to control multiple independent node.js script from one file (either php or node.js).
While 3rd question is additional one to clarify my doubt.